# Что нужно реализовать для авторизации любого вида в spring через postman?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

**Дано:**

Сервер на `spring` - там есть БД `postgresql` и возможность считывать/записывать туда данные.

**Задача:**

Сделать авторизацию любого вида для возможности вызывать запросы вида `http://domen/users/all?token=myToken` из любого приложения (postman, android, js)

**Проблема:**

Потратил много часов на попытки реализовать что-то из пример с оф. сайта. Ничего не заработало. Пробовал запускать примеры (авторизация через `facebook`) - они работают, но только при вызове из браузера. При попытках вызвать тоже самое из `postman` ругается на какие-то токены отсутствующие или на то, что не видит передаваемых в запросе данных (токен от `facebook`). Ни одно решение из сети не помогло. Пробовал `spring-session` использовать - но там непонятно как решать конфликты с уже имеющейся БД - как решить проблему ненаходящейся таблицы с сессиями за много часов так и не понял и вообще не уверен, что сессии это то, что мне нужно.

Т.е. проблема в том, что громадные простыни кода и текста в туториалах и репозитории с примерами не дают представления о том, как их связать с чем-то уже имеющимся или как их использовать в чуть других условиях.

**Вопрос:**

Какие шаги нужно выполнить для добавления возможности получить токен для запросов? Имеется в виду набор запросов в интернет, сделав которые я смог бы понять что и как мне нужно сделать.

Comment: в сторону [JWT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) смотрели?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, попробуйте Scribe API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void signIn(@PathVariable String type, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    switch (type) {
        case "vk":
            final OAuth20Service vk = socialService.BuildVKService(vkClientId, vkClientSecret, getAppURI(request) + "/social/callback");
            response.sendRedirect(vk.getAuthorizationUrl());
            break;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String callback(@RequestParam String code, HttpServletRequest request0) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
    log.info(code);

    final OAuth20Service vk = socialService.BuildVKService(vkClientId, vkClientSecret, getAppURI(request0) + "/social/callback");
    return socialService.tryVkAuth(vk, code, request0);
}

public OAuth20Service BuildVKService(String clientId, String clientSecret, String callback) {
    return vkService = new ServiceBuilder(clientId)
            .apiSecret(clientSecret)
            .scope("email")
            .callback(callback)
            .build(VkontakteApi.instance());
}

public String tryVkAuth(OAuth20Service vk, String code, HttpServletRequest request0) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
    final OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = vk.getAccessToken(code);
    final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL_VK);
    vk.signRequest(accessToken, request);
    final Response response = vk.execute(request);

    final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
    final JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("response");
    final JSONObject resultObj = array.getJSONObject(0);

    final long userId = resultObj.getLong("id");

    final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication != null) {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof MAccount) {
            final MAccount mAccount0 = (MAccount) authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (mAccount0.getVkAccessToken() == null || mAccount0.getVkAccessToken().isEmpty()) {
                mAccount0.setVkAccessToken(String.valueOf(userId));
                mAccountService.save(mAccount0);
                return "redirect:/cp";
            }
        }
    }

    final MAccount mAccount = mAccountService.findBySocialCode(String.valueOf(userId));
    if (mAccount == null) {
        request0.getSession().setAttribute("vk_social_code", userId);
        return "redirect:/enter";
    }

    //TODO simple message or Response answer
    if (mAccount.isBanned()) {
        return "redirect:/enter";
    }

    //TODO simple message or Response answer
    if (!mAccount.isEnabled()) {
        return "redirect:/enter";
    }

    final MAccount mAccount = mAccountService.findBySocialCode(String.valueOf(userId));
    if (mAccount == null) {
        request0.getSession().setAttribute("vk_social_code", userId);
        return "redirect:/enter";
    }

    final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(mAccount.getUsername(), mAccount.getPassword(), mAccount.getAuthorities());
    token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request0));
    final Authentication authentication1 = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication1);

    return "redirect:/cp";
}
```

Comment: Ого как сложно( Спасибо, попробую разобраться как это прикрутить)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб конечно минус всего этого дела, что на запрос и на колбек нужно постоянно собирать сервис иначе смысл автоматизации теряется, вчера пол вечера потратил и так и не придумал как по-другому сделать. Особо ничего сложного нет - отослали запрос контроллеру -> собрали сервис -> выдали респонс ссылку на апи сайта, куда перенаправляем клиент -> по прописанному колбеку возвращаемся на контроллер -> билдим сервис -> считываем полученый токен для аторизации в апи сайта -> авторизируемся -> шлем респонс на получение информации -> парсим информацию .

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Глянуть семплы можно тут -> https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/tree/master/scribejava-apis/src/test/java/com/github/scribejava/apis/examples

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю) Пока что выглядит сложнее тех примеров, которые я уже смотрел. А у меня даже простые не заводятся(